# Will there be an impact on the graph database if multiple SUBMIT JOB STATS are carried out simultaneously?

Tags: graph-databases, nebula-graph

NebulaGraph Version: 3.1.0

Deployment method: distributed / single machine

Does submitting multiple SUBMIT JOB STATS tasks at the same time affect the gallery?

We need to calculate the number of points and edges of each graph dataset.
But if I have multiple graphs and run dozens of SUBMIT JOB STATS tasks at the same time, what is NebulaGraph’s mechanism for executing job tasks?

Will this affect the NebulaGraph clusters, for example, all resources are placed on the job task, causing other operations to freeze, etc.?

Will NebulaGraph execute all job tasks sequentially by jobid?

Answer (score 0):

In the same space, jobs are executed serially. If multiple graphs execute SUBMIT JOB STATS, they are executed separately and in parallel.

Whether executing multiple STATS jobs affects the performance of the cluster depends on the architecture of the cluster and the capability of each machine. If the data volume stored in the cluster is very large and the machine capability is relatively not so good, it is not recommended to run multiple STATS jobs together.